Backup Migrate Error: "Could not create a temporary file to write to.", but /tmp folder is already 777 on Ubuntu server
I'm trying to manually backup using backup and migrate module on Drupal 9.4, but I keep getting this error:
Could not create a temporary file to write to.
I checked with file system page and it says the temporary folder is: /tmp
I checked the /tmp folder and its already set to: drwxrwxrwt  16 root root
I'm not sure what else I can do to resolve this permissions issue?

This question would benefit greatly by having a stack trace.
